# Help with でも functions

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-でも

I have this sentence: "どんなスポーツでもこの三つがなければ上手にならないと考えられている。" But I can't figure it out what sense でも is giving to the sentence. In my head is something like "although it's expected sports to be good, they aren't going to be good if they don't have these three." 
is it right or wrong, could you show any light on this please! How would you translate this phrase?

Comment: Do you have more context, or only this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

> 「どんなスポーツ**でも**この三{みっ}つがなければ上手{じょうず}にならないと考{かんが}えられている。」

「でも」 in this context means "any" in the sense of "regardless of".

The basic pattern is:

> 「どの or どんな + Noun + でも」

「どんなスポーツでも」 = "in any sports"

「どんな人でも」 = "anyone", "everyone"

「どんな国でも」 = "in any country"

> In my head is something like "although it's expected sports to be good, they aren't going to be good if they don't have these three."

Not sure how you get "it's expected sports to be good" or even what that means.

My own TL:

> "In any sports (or "regardless of the type of sport"), it is believed that one could not become good/competitive without possessing those three (skills/things)."

Comment: It's just a way of thinking to see If I understood the concept of a grammar point that I thought it was the case, but turned out I haven't learned this one yet. Thank you for answering, it help me loads ;)